# How to get particular value using `DataSnapshot` in `Firebase`

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get particular value using from `DataSnapshot`.
I am attaching the screenshot here so kindly check and help me to get particular value from `Realtime Database`.
[image]

Actually I am implementing `chat` application in which I want to get value of `user` from `group_list`.
Here is my code.

```
    private void loadTotalGroupList() {

        referenceMainUrl = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://pure-coda-174710.firebaseio.com");
        referenceGroupList = referenceMainUrl.child("group_list");

        //Check if child is available or not.
        referenceGroupList.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


                    Log.e("dataSnapshot","  ==>"+dataSnapshot);
                    Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                    Log.e("newPost","  ==>"+newPost);

                   Log.e("user: ","==>" + newPost.get("user"));  // Here I am getting null value


                } else {
                    Log.e("Child not found", " >>>");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }
```

and `log` showing like this. ***DataSnapshot { key = group_list, value = {First Group={-KtBH9gnTszNxcXjNu9A={message=assaasas, user=sakib}}} }***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by using `addChildEventListener`

```
    referenceGroupList.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {



            Log.e("dataSnapshot KEY", " ==>" + dataSnapshot.getKey());

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Here `dataSnapshot.getKey()` returns all sub child of it.

Answer (score 0):

You're listening to the location `/group_list` in your code.  That means a a snapshot from that location will contain the following:

```
/First Group
    /-KtBH9gnTszNxcXjNu9A
        message = "..."
        user = "..."
```

If you want to get the user value from that location, you'll have to dig into it using each intermediate path:

```
dataSnapshot.child("First Group").child("-KtBH9gnTszNxcXjNu9A").child("user").getValue()
```

Or more simply:

```
dataSnapshot.child("First Group"/-KtBH9gnTszNxcXjNu9A/user").getValue()
```

You can't skip the middle paths in the snapshot.  Alternatively, you may want to listen to a location closer to the value you want:

```
referenceMainUrl.child("group_list/First Group/-KtBH9gnTszNxcXjNu9A");
```

Comment: @ Doug Stevenson Thanks you for reply but I have query which is everytime when new group will be create then this value `-KtBH9gnTszNxcXjNu9A` will be differ so how to I manage it. I have no idea how to get only `user` from all group list.

Answer (score 0):

This code runs in a loop and gives you values for all the 'user's

```
DatabaseReference dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("group_list").child("First_Group");
    dRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String userName = snapshot.child("user").getValue(String.class);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```